# content.field_name does not render anything

Tags: theming

i've made a twig file for my 'test' content type called node--test.html.twig. That works fine using {{ content }} to print the node.

I've a custom field with the machine name field_text, the following prints fine:
{{ node.field_text.value }}

For some reason i cant get {{ content.field_text }} to work. I also can't get content.body or any other subset of content to work in any node type.

I must be doing something really daft - thanks for the help

Comment: The solution was to uninstall Field Layout module (a core - experimental module).

Answer (score 2):

`content.<field_name>` should work.
try adding `{{ dump(content|keys) }}` to your template, does it show anything?

Comment: i get the following:

website/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Debug.php:60:
array (size=1)
  0 => string '_field_layout' (length=13)

Comment: if relevant - i'm using bootstrap within a subtheme

Comment: - just tried with other themes, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Do you have anything special installed? Any idea where the `_field_layout` comes from?
I'm using bootstrap aswell, it should work the way you are trying so I'm guessing you are using some module that changes the templates?
Try setting `debug: true` in the `twig.config`-section in sites/default/services.yml, after that the page source code should tell you which templates are being used.

Comment: Field Layout is a core experimental module - can't remember why i enabled it - may have been enabled by something else i was playing with. I've uninstalled it and its all working now! Thanks very much both of you - I will upvote as soon as my newbie reputation status on this forum allows

Comment: Thanks for this, somehow I had that module enabled and the content.field_name shortcut wasn't working. Disabled Field Layout and everything's working again!